# 'this' is undefined in React component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

When I try to execute the below code, the value of `this` within the function `renderContents` is `undefined`.

I had thought that fat arrow functions bound this automatically. Is this not the case? If not, how can I ensure that `this` is passed to the function `renderContents`?

**Code sample:**

```
class Box extends React.Component {
  renderContents = () => {
      console.log(this); // undefined
      return (
        <div></div>
        )
  }

   render() {
      const { 
        someValue,
      } = this.props;

      return (
            <div>
              {someValue ? this.renderContents() : null}
            </div>
            );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. Are you sure this example is enough to reproduce what you're describing?

Comment: It is enough. Someone answered telling me to not use arrow functions, but the answer is now gone. I dropped the arrow function syntax and everything works just like that.

Comment: It isn't though. Using a method is definitely an alternative approach that should _also_ work, but there should also be nothing wrong with your code as shown that would make it not work.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle with your code working as-is as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/bvpe4j39/150/

Comment: It is just the arrow function. Arrow functions do not have a context, meaning there is no "this" specifically attached to it. `...An arrow function does not create its own this, the this value of the enclosing execution context is used...` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. I just called it like this:

```
ReactDOM.render((<Box someValue={true} />), document.getElementById('content'));
```

and I got the value of ***this***:

[image]

So I think the problem would be, you aren't calling it right, are you setting ***someValue***??

Comment: That's not the case. Thank you though.

Comment: Then please provide us of more information. Because I cannot reproduce the unless I call it bad.

Comment: This example definitely not enough to reproduce the issue. I tried your example code too and it worked fine. There is something else influencing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You make mistake in renderContent method. You declare it as function and it have no context of your component.
Please try to declare methods like this:

```
renderContent() {
 ...your code...
}
```

Instead this:

```
renderContent = () => {}
```

Comment: @TylerSebastian according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions "arrow functions" do not have a context by themselves, meaning he is right.

Comment: @camou did you read your source? "the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used" meaning it would take value of the enclosing React component

Comment: @TylerSebastian I'm sorry but I believe that is incorrect, the execution context is not the component but the global object in this case. I would have to do more tests but I'm pretty sure that is the case. Let me know if you do some tests.

Comment: @TylerSebastian I did some testing and, as I suspected, the execution context is the global object at the time the arrow function is declared and not the React component, let me know if you happen to reproduce it otherwise. Aside from our current discussion, I believe OP is using a transpiler of some sorts that prints undefined instead of 'window', I mention this because `renderContent = () => {}` is not the correct syntax to declare a method in ES engines, meaning that V8 and others will throw a syntax error.

Comment: @camou can I see your example? from the top-level comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bvpe4j39/150/  <- this is default behaviour for most engines.

Comment: @camou: `renderContent = () => {}` is the [*public class fields* proposal](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/). `renderContent = () => {}` is evaluated inside the constructor.

Comment: @FelixKling cool, didn't know that, but I understand it is still a proposal, correct? https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields

Comment: Ok, I see now. @TylerSebastian, basically, we are both correct :). As it is most likely OP is using a transpiler for React, some transpilers (e.g. Babel) add additional proposed ES.next features that are still drafts, like this one which is not currently implemented in V8 alone. All my tests were done in V8 without transpilers which right now does not support that syntax. Without a transpiler: https://jsbin.com/gebociz/6/edit?js,console , With a transpiler: https://jsbin.com/wazigoq/1/edit?js,console .

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried to add an constructor method?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}
```

EDIT:

Instead of using arrow functions, you could bind the context in constructor like this:

```
class Box extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.renderContents = this.renderContents.bind(this)
    }

    renderContents() {
        console.log(this);
        return (
            <div></div>
        )
    }

    render() {
       const { 
           someValue,
       } = this.props;

       return (
           <div>
               {someValue ? this.renderContents() : null}
           </div>
       );
    }
}
```

In react classes just some methods are implicitly binded (render, componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount, etc.), other methods you have to bind manually in constructor or use arrow functions.

Comment: Having a constructor does not make a difference.

Comment: FYI, your edit is essentially what the syntax in the question does. `renderContents = () => {` is a proposed syntax for values initialized in the constructor, meaning it is a `renderContents` property containing a function bound to `this`.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I know, I use arrow functions in react components all the time. But since the code he provided was clearly right, I just proposed s different approach. Just as I wrote: _...bind manually in constructor **or use arrow functions.**_